# Creating and manipulating instances of different types of objects at runtime knowing only thes type names

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to create an inherited form for displaying information from different tables in my database, with four buttons (Close, New, Edit, Delete). But as the displayed information is may be from a different table everytime, clicking "Delete" would mean deleting an object of a different type based on the table I have opened. I have implemented the New button and Close and everything is ok. Here is the code.

I create a class PubliTypes and i put this

```
    Public Enum OBJECT_TYPE
    Program
    Student
    Level
    SchoolYear
    End Enum

    Public Function GetObjectTypes(ByVal objectT As PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE) As Object

    Select Case objectT

        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.Level
            Return New Level
        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.SchoolYear
            Return New SchoolYear
        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.Program
            Return New Program
        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.Student
            Return New Student
    End Select
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

I create 2 properties in the inherited from to store the name(string) of the currently displayed object(program, student, etc) I call it ManagedObject, and another property that stores full info about selectedItem, it is of type managedObject.

the problem is for example if student list is displayed, and user click "Delete" how do I access the members of Student to delete a specific student (I have the class implemented and working fine. Now suppose the selected object is program or schoolYear. How can I cast an SelectedItem to ManagedOBject and Instanciate it? (an object of type managedOBject is anything -program, student, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can make the classes implement an interface. Then you'd have a bit more type safety. From that point, `Object` is not a great thing. In the posted code, you'd then have the interface as return type.

If the knowledge the object's class implemented this interface is not enough, you can test the type with the `TypeOf Is` Operator. However you cannot use `TypeOf IsNot`, but the workaround is trivial.

With that you can get the type the following:

```
If TypeOf objectT Is Level Then
    ' Your Code
ElseIf TypeOf objectT Is SchoolYear
    '...
End If
```

When *Your Code* often starts with

```
Dim objectTAsLevel As Level = CType(objectT, Level)
```

you should use

```
Dim objectTAsLevel As Level = TryCast(objectT, Level)
Dim objectAsSchoolYear = TryCast(objectT, SchoolYear)

If objectTAsLevel IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Level stuff
ElseIf objectAsSchoolYear IsNot Nothing Then
    ' ...
End If
```

before any type check and then test, if the new variable is Nothing. `TryCast` will return Nothing if the type cast didn't go well.

And after all, if you use **Roslyn** or don't mind installing it, you can do this:

```
Select Case objectT
    Case lvl As Level
        ' Your code here.
    Case year As SchoolYear

    Case prog As Program

    Case stdnt As Student ' When codition

    Case Else
        ' Error message?
End Select
```

That works similar to `Try` blocks. You can even use `When` to check a `Boolean` condition.

Comment: Thank you mr Bolpat. I figured out what I needed was reflection. As a beginer, i didn't even know about the concept. Now I am reading some docs before I try it back. Anyway, As a plan to have a lot of object types, I was not opting for test structures.